# Clang AST find only syntax errors

Tags: c++, abstract-syntax-tree, llvm-clang, clang-tidy

I'm using Clang to create some internal static code analyzers. For one of the analyzers, we need to take a raw string and check if it has any syntax errors.
We shouldn't consider missing symbols, missing headers, invalid function calls etc. as invalid syntax - as the only meaning is to see if it's a valid C/C++ code or not.

I thought initially that I could do it with `ASTUnit`:

```
  auto AST = tooling::buildASTFromCodeWithArgs(MyCode,
                                               Args,
                                               "input.cc",
                                               "clang-tool",
                                               std::make_shared<PCHContainerOperations>(),
                                               tooling::getClangStripDependencyFileAdjuster(),
                                               tooling::FileContentMappings(),
                                               &DiagConsumer);

  llvm::outs() << "hasUncompilableErrorOccurred " << AST->getDiagnostics().hasUncompilableErrorOccurred() << "\n";
  llvm::outs() << "hasUnrecoverableErrorOccurred " << AST->getDiagnostics().hasUnrecoverableErrorOccurred() << "\n";
  llvm::outs() << "hasErrorOccurred " << AST->getDiagnostics().hasErrorOccurred() << "\n";
```

Taking two inputs: `Hello world` and `#include <undefined.h>` - both yields 1 in the outputs above - even when `#include <undefined.h>` is a correct C statement, but the issue with it (unlike with `hello world`, which's not a valid C code) - is that `undefined.h` is missing. Similarly, taking: `int* p = malloc(sizeof(int));` as code will yield error in all of these calls if `stdlib.h` wasn't included.

I try to avoid such errors, so that every case, except from `hello world`, will be considered as valid code.

I did tried to iterate over it by creating a Raw Lexer, but it won't give me sufficient information.

```
  Lexer Lex(CharRange.getBegin(), PP->getLangOpts(), Text.data(),
                       Text.data(), Text.data() + Text.size());

  Token RawTok;
  do {
    Lex.LexFromRawLexer(RawTok);
    llvm::outs() << "\t- " << RawTok.getKind() << "\n";
  } while (RawTok.isNot(tok::eof));
```

I'd love to get any suggestions!